# How to handle API which return file like (image,pdf etc) in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

When I am hitting an API it returns file like an image or PDF in react native so is there any package of **Expo** which provide the ability to download these files into local storage, kindly give an idea about any **Expo Package** to handle this.
This is the data I've got in the console.
data: `"%PDF-1.5\r\n%����\r\n19 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Cat..."`

Comment: Your question is bit too broad. please add some information and code of what you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for is [`expo-file-system`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/)

Comment: The above is only working when i have uri but in my case i have file instead of uri. kindly suggest any library which handles files

Comment: There is also a package called react-native-fs to read write files. I am not sure if it would work in expo tho :(

Comment: It doesn't work because this package is needed to link with react-native and expo doesn't support this kind of packages